# Add Windows User Control to a WPF View

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, user-controls

I need to add a Windows form User Control (Barcode_Scanner.cs) to a WPF View (MainWindow.xaml)

Is there a simple way to do this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is your UserControl made in WinForms? and you want to add it to WPF Window?

Comment: Just put it in a `WindowsFormsHost` control (its in your toolbox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can host `Windows.Forms` controls using the WPF `WindowsFormsHost` element.

Example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:winforms="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
        xmlns:myControls="clr-namespace:MyContromNamespace;assembly=MyContromNamespace"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="195" Width="191" Name="UI">
    <Grid>
        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <winforms:Button Text="StackOverflow" />
        </WindowsFormsHost>

        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <myControls:MyUserControl  />
        </WindowsFormsHost>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: How would I add a custom control though? One that I have created.

Comment: just set a `xmlns` definition for your custom controls namespace, added example to answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with [WindowsFormsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

So the first thing that we need to do (after creating a new WPF project) is add a few references. You can do this by by right-clicking on the references folder in the solution explorer, and choosing "Add Reference":

[image]

Then you will get a dialog like this:

[image]

[and so on wpf-tutorial-using-winforms-in-wpf](http://tech.pro/tutorial/786/wpf-tutorial-using-winforms-in-wpf)

Comment: You usally don't have to add the refernce manually, in VS2010 and VS2012 the `System.Windows.Forms` references are added automaticly when you place a `WindowsFormsHost` on your `WPF` element

Comment: @ sa_ddam213:yes,i just go into details:D